# Capture Right Click on HTML DIV

Tags: javascript, html, events

I am trying to paint cell on a html page, where each cell is a DIV, I need to be able to capture right click event on any of these cells, How can I do that?

```
<script>
function fn(event)
{
 alert('hello'+event.button);
}
</script>

<div id="cell01"
         class=""
         onclick="fn(event);"
         style="left: 1471px; width: 24px; height: 14px; top: 64px; text-align: center; position: absolute; background-color: rgb(128, 128, 0);">1</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at this: [Javascript - event properties](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html). Value for right mouse button is `2`, although also note that it recommends using `mousedown` or `mouseup` events rather than click.

Here is a sample from the page showing right click detection:

```
function doSomething(e) {
    var rightclick;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.which) rightclick = (e.which == 3);
    else if (e.button) rightclick = (e.button == 2);
    alert('Rightclick: ' + rightclick); // true or false
}
```

Comment: +1 - for the example - although you deserve a +2 since I gave jani a +1 too for being quick on the draw, but you included sample code ;)

Answer (score 49):

the easiest way

```
<div style="height: 100px; background-color: red;" oncontextmenu="window.alert('test');return false;"></div>
```

Comment: This is actually using an HTML attribute as an "event listener", but technically it IS still allowing you to run javascript code once you've captured the event.  So, this should be the answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you check out [the event handling page on Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html), as it includes a guide to capturing right clicks as well as a comprehensive guide to avoid cross-browser issues with events.

A word of warning though: Not all browsers allow detecting right clicks by default.